# Vuetify rules message translation using nuxt i18n

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I want to display translated rule messages, when Vuetify validation fails

Template section

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="message.name"
    outlined
    :label="$t('page.contact.form.name')"
    :rules=nameValidationRules
></v-text-field>
```

Script section

```
const nameValidationRules = ref([requiredRule, blankValidator])
```

Validator rules are kept in "validationRules.ts"

```
export const requiredRule = (value: any): string | boolean => !!value || 'This field is required';
export const blankValidator = (value: string | null | undefined): string | boolean => !value || !!value?.trim() || 'This field cannot be blank.';
```

I want to replace the 'This field is required' with i18n variable.

Comment: Validators should return the **key** of the message rather than the message itself. Then in your script section you will have to check the return value from each validator - and if it is a String, then use it as an argument for `this.$t()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass translation function to the rule definition :

```js
const {t} = useI18n()

const nameValidationRules = ref([requiredRule(t), blankValidator(t)])
```

```js
export const requiredRule = (t: any) => (value: any): string | boolean => !!value || t('required');
export const blankValidator = (t: any) => (value: string | null | undefined): string | boolean => !value || !!value?.trim() || t('not_blank');
```